# How do I turn off client side validation in MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, client-side-validation

I have a framework for client side validation that I'd prefer to use over the existing one that ships with ASP.NET MVC 3.

Does anyone know how to disable it in MVC 3?

I have tried the following:

```
HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = false;
HtmlHelper.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = false;
```

And this in the web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="false"/> 
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="false"/> 
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Neither have worked :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

enable unobtrusive and disable clientvalidation.

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="false"/> 
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/> 
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I just tried it (actually with both false) and it works fine. Its possible your page was being cached as well. I recommend keeping UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled=true because of the lighter ajax attributes it adds.

Answer (score 1):

Disable it in your web.config:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="false"/>
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like the setting needed to be set in the base web.config. **IT SEEMS TO BE IGNORED IF YOU TRY TO SET IT IN THE VIEW web.config FILE!**