# Turn of JavaScript and ASP.NET validators do not fire on server side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, validation

On my website When I turn off JavaScript the ASP.NET validators do not fire at the server side as I would expect.

For instance required field validators are not firing when I have JavaScript off.

I thought that one of the benefits of the built in ASP.NET validators was protection from this so I am confused.

Comment: use this syntax for your button onclientclick
onclientclick=javascript:return JsFunctionName();

please post your code.

Comment: ASP.net validators were never server side. They work client side.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the property enableclientvalidation to false on your validators it will not do any clients side JS validation for web forms, there is a similar option for MVC [How do I turn off client side validation in MVC 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254213/how-do-i-turn-off-client-side-validation-in-mvc-3)

However if you are using web forms there are many things that will not work without JS.

Answer (score 0):

use this syntax for your button `onclientclick`

```
onclientclick=javascript:return JsFunctionName();
```

and

**1)check your return false and  true code**

**2) must use validation group in all validation control and button**