# Can I turn off all the MVC client validation by deleting entries from the web.config

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following setting in my `web.config:`

```
<appSettings>
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

I am not using any client-side validation.

Should I set these to `false` or is it okay just to delete both entries?

Comment: Possible duplicate?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254213/how-do-i-turn-off-client-side-validation-in-mvc-3

Comment: leave everything as is. If you don't want to use client-side validation, just don't use any model annotations. But don't go removing and tweaking things for this affect.

Comment: I checked the link and it says - "I recommend keeping UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled=true because of the lighter ajax attributes it adds." I am even more confused now. Also why should I leave it set these to true if they are actually not true and I don't need them ?

Comment: Yes. That's why you should leave BOTH settings to **true** and use validation on the fields you want validated. Where is the remaining confusion?

Answer (score 11):

If you don't want it, set it to false.  That way you don't even have to guess what the default is later on, and others on the project can see right away that having it turned off was your intention.

Also remove the client validation from the bundleconfig to prevent your users from needless downloads.

Comment: This is the right answer.  If you are not going to use **ANY** client side validation, turn it off (set EnableCLientSideValidation to false.  When this is false, the second item will not be used regardless if it set to true or false).  This will prevent the framework from rendering any of the HTML5 attributes or the big ugly <CDATA> section from MVC 1 and 2.  See here for more information on the settings: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html

Answer (score 9):

**There are 2 different Settings in `Web.config` that are coupled, but not synonymous.**

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="false"/>
```

Determines whether or not Client Validation is enabled. If the value is set to ***false***, your model annotations (`required, min, max`, etc) will not create client-side attributes or behaviors.

```
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
```

Determines whether ***ASP.NET*** will use ***JQuery*** for client side Asynchronous tasks, or raw ***JavaScript***.

If `UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled=false`, your Client-Side Validation will still work, but will use Raw ***JavaScript*** over ***JQuery***.

---

**What is significance of using JQuery over JavaScript?**

Some environments choose not to use ***JQuery***. They have heavily customized UI frameworks. ***JQuery*** may already be in use in a custom fashion. Or a different JS library may be in use for all Asynchronous enhancement

**What are dis-advantages of using raw JavaScript?**

- Your ***Ajax*** helpers will not work without ***JQuery*** (UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled).
- Raw ***JavaScript*** is messy and fills up your markup with a lot of **stuff**. JQuery creates lighter and cleaner markup. (The advantage of "***lighter ajax attributes***")
- Your raw ***Javascript*** will be less robust, and possibly less efficient. Keep in mind, the ***ASP.NET JavaScript*** libraries have not evolved in 3 years (long before the release of ***MVC 3***).

---

**In Conclusion:**

If you want to disable Client-Side validation, set

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="false"/>
```

But I recommend you leave `ClientValidationEnabled` set to `true`. If you don't decorate your model with validation annotation, the framework won't render validation attributes. Best to leave your options open and decide for each ***View*** / ***ViewModel*** where to use Client-Side Validation.

I recommend against disabling ***UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled***. There are too many subtle ways ***JQuery*** is used by ***ASP.NET MVC Framework***. And this will not disable Client-Side validation.

**Important Note:** Don't delete either entry. If you want to disable one, just set it to `false`. By deleting either entry, you leave yourself at the mercy of the Framework's default behavior (which may change over time).

Comment: Dave - just a quick clarification, the UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled setting actually controls how the client side validation is rendered.  With this set to true, the HTML5 style attributes are rendered on each form input.  With it set to false, the old school JSON blob of <CDATA> text is rendered at the end of the form.  While true that the true setting uses jQuery.validate, the false setting will fall back to the old school Microsoft.Ajax.Validate methods and not plain javascript.  http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html.  Just 2 cents!

Comment: @Tommy, thanks for the contribution. To clarify, I though the Microsoft.Ajax.Validate library was written in raw Javascript. Is that incorrect?

Comment: You're probably right, I think it is. The way I read your answer initially made it sound like one was on their own and there was not any framework support :)  Anyways, I came across that link when I was looking into the question and though it provided some good info on the attributes in question!

Comment: @Tommy, I tried to speak to OP's question very specifically; Answering why the `UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled` flag should be set to `true` and how that affected lighter ajax attributes OP was so confused about. I'm not sure why my answer is any **LESS** correct.

Comment: I know this is old. But, leaving this set to true and "just not using validation attributes" means you have no validation of your <<View>>model server side either.

Comment: @PilotBob, agreed. And, in fact, that, IMO, is the better way to go. But the OP's question took a different route.

Answer (score 2):

If you not reference the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` or delete it from bundles the validation will be disabled. However based on the web.config parameter the `@Html` helpers generate or not the html attributes used by this script. So I recommend remove the script and set `ClientValidationEnabled` false.
If you not using the `@Ajax` helper, the `UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled` value makes no defference.

Answer (score 2):

Unobstrusive settings are Ok.

You need to set `ClientValidationEnabled` to `false`.

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="false"/> 
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/> 
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Hope this helps.